# Integrate counters with gatling

Tags: scala, counter, gatling, grafana

I want to know if it's possible integrate the Kamon counters placed in my code like mailbox-size with Gatling to obtain graphics of this in the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Use InfluxDB + Graphana, or Graphite as metric storage + dashboard
- Have Kamon push into the storage through StatsD
- Have Gatling push into InfluxDB or Graphite: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.5/realtime_monitoring/index.html

This way, you can have all your metrics, from both Gatling and your system under test side by side in the same dashboard.